# Need to add column in dataset based on If condition

Tags: sas

I have one sas dataset so want to check of that value and column_position not exist then add that obs in dataset else if value of column is not exist and column_position is same then replace that col_position (for example at 15th row there is one observation so now I want to add new value to 15th row then original 15th row goes to 16th obs , 16th obs goes to 17th...etc (*n*+1 r lag function not sure)
 **I am trying this, but not working properly, please help me**

```
data test;
input value $ data_type $ length col_pos;
datalines;
harry varchar 100 1
henry number 100 2
homry varchar 100 3
;

%macro add_column(value,data_type,length,col_pos);

data _null_;
set test;
if value="&value" then call symput('col_name',1)
else call symput('col_name',2)
if col_pos="&col_pos" then call symput ('col_pos',1)
else call symput('col_pos,2)
run;

if &col_name=2 and &col_pos=2 then;
%do;
  data test;
set test;
value="&value";
data_type="&data_type";
length="&length";
col_pos="&col_pos";
output;
run;
%end;
%mend;
%add_column(alex,varchar,100,4);
```

Suppose if value changed and col_pos same 
For example, I need to replace 2nd col_pos and 2nd col_pos from test dataset above should go to 3rd
%add_column(joe,varchar,100,2);
if &col_name=2(as value is different) and &col_pos=1(col_pos is same i.e 2) then; (I am trying to write this but didn't worked)
 '2' col_pos is same

Please help me with this

Comment: The question is somewhat awkward because the sample data involves rows of column names, the title indicates you want to insert a column (and most readers would think a vertical column) and the question+data shows you want to insert or replace a row.

Comment: You also have a bare `if` inside the macro indicating a misunderstanding of macro and code generation scope.  If you can update the question to show the process without any macro code it will be easier to understand if a macro is needed at all, or if so, how that macro can be coded.

Comment: I am sorry , I need to add a value (update dataset) and yes actually i forgot to include %if and %then but still its not working